# What is the maximum length of a client ID on OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Is there any maximum limitations?

I curious to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of knowing really that is something that would be configured by the owner of the authorization server.